# Slow query stops apache from getting answer

Tags: mysql

I have a problem where I can not query my mysql db until other queries are done. This happens when I run a heavy sql-query (30s) from apache, or when I ran a series of sql-querys from within the same apache-request.

Since my queries are only selects (no updates or modifications and no transactions) I think it should be possible to run simulatanious queries. How can I make this possible?

I am using Zend_Db::factory($config->db->adapter, $dbConfig);
I am not sure if this limits the connections or try to re use same connection always. I manually close the connection between each call in the "serie of calls".

/Peter

Comment: Are you re-using the same connection?

Comment: If you run "show processlist" while the big server is running AND another query is waiting, what does it tell you? Most likely your hardware just isn't able to cope running more than one query at once. A select shouldn't block other selects.

Comment: Sorry, 'server' should've read 'query'

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more information in order to help diagnose this problem.  What table types are you using, InnoDB or MyISAM?  Are there any transactions being used?  Perhaps you could edit your question and post an example of the queries you are running.

Comment: Have done some testing. It only blocks other apache calls. Calls fom query browser works. Does not apache manage multiple calls?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a connection pool set up in Apache which is running out of connections. I'm not sure which module you're using in apache, but if its [mod_dbd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dbd.html) then check your `DBDMax` parameter.